# Playing a mp3 from terminal to a usb sound card

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, ffmpeg, soundcard, audio-jack

Hi I know this question is really specific but I want to know how to play a mp3 or any other audio file format from terminal to **only** a external soundcard I think such a thing is possible with ffmpeg but I don't know how

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806447/how-i-can-play-any-audiofile-to-any-connected-usb-audio-card#43818459) in stackoverflow

Comment: Looks like mpg123 might be able to do this although I cannot test on my system. What does `mpg123 --list-devices` show on your system?